# jQuery Checkboxes Style

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with styling checkboxes with jQuery mobile.

My code is here:

html:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id=list>
    <h3>Neighborhoods</h3>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="districts" data-iconpos="right"></fieldset>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var container = $('#districts');
var place="place";
var int=1;
var checkBox = $('<p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-'+int+'a" id=""checkbox-'+int+'a" class="custom" /><label for="checkbox-'+int+'a">'+place+'</label><\p>');
    container.append(checkBox);
```

head of html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobiledragdrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I want is [that(Vertical Group)](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/checkbox/)

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: if i create the checkboxes they are in plain html style and not in jquery style like the sample in the link

Comment: Show some more code. Did you include the correct jQuery files (+CSS)

Comment: let us know your query.... nothing is clear where you are stuck?